# KeyError: Float64Index Error when looking through excel sheet and analyzing it

Tags: python

Hi I am super new to python and I keep running into this error.

```
KeyError: "None of [Float64Index([ 0.0,  0.0, 17.0, 17.0,  0.0, 17.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 18.0,\n              ...\n              21.0, 19.0,  0.0, 29.0,  0.0, 18.0,  0.0, 15.0, 14.0, 19.0],\n             dtype='float64', 
length=1206)] are in the [index]"
```

My code is the following:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 


Trauma = pd.read_excel('SSAGA_total_with_trauma_sums.xlsx')

Trauma = Trauma.replace(np.nan, 0, regex=True)

# Create column with # of traumas that occurred before age of onset (MJ2ageon) 

def pre_trauma(row):
    sum = []
    temp=0
    for i in range(1,18):
        item = 'PT1a' + str(i) + 'Age'
        onset_age = Trauma.MJ2AgeOn
        if row[item] < row[onset_age]:       
            temp = temp + 1 
            sum.append(temp)
    return temp   


Trauma['Tbeforeonset'] = Trauma.apply(pre_trauma, axis=1)
print(Trauma)

Trauma.to_excel('MJ2ageon.xlsx', index = False)
```

I am trying to get the number of traumas that occurred before age of onset(MJ2AgeOn). So far I have tried to change the range of the values that exist. But that did not work. Each column name is PT1a#Age so I tried excluding the 0 by using the range 1,18. I understand that there are methods to skip certain items but I am not sure if the issue is that I am looking at PT1a0Age anymore. The issue that is in my code could be something entirely different I am not sure.

Comment: Where did you get that error?

Comment: @TimRoberts At the function "def pre_trauma(row):"

Comment: No, I mean which line of code?  That line clearly cannot cause an error.  If you post a link to your Excel sheet, we can all try it ourselves.

Comment: @TimRoberts Here is the link to the de-identified excel sheet: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SLMclCuVewBuk-0xXpqcrrFQEK1yXRAv/view?usp=sharing

Comment: There is no column in your sheet called `MJ2AgeOn`.

Comment: Columns past 9 are "Pt1a10Ag", not "Pt1a10Age".  And because you replaced all the NaNs with 0s, those are all going to count as "less than" any age.

Comment: @TimRoberts The code is now working thank you for all of your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I can assume that `Trauma.MJ2AgeOn` was supposed to be a constant (21?), then this code seems to do what you want.  I removed "sum", since you never use it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

Trauma = pd.read_excel('SSAGA_total_with_trauma_sums.xlsx')
Trauma = Trauma.replace(np.nan, 0)
print(Trauma)
print(Trauma.columns)

# Create column with # of traumas that occurred before age of onset (MJ2ageon) 

def pre_trauma(row):
    temp=0
    for i in range(1,18):
        item = ('PT1a' + str(i) + 'Age')[:8]
        if row[item] and row[item] < 21:
            temp += 1 
    return temp

Trauma['Tbeforeonset'] = Trauma.apply(pre_trauma, axis=1)
print(Trauma)

Trauma.to_excel('MJ2ageon.xlsx', index = False)
```